# H2 Database Postgres Mode Upsert

Tags: java, h2, upsert

When H2 database is in Postgres Mode, how do I check if it supports following statement (upsert / on conflict)

```
INSERT INTO event_log_poller_state (aggregate_type, consumer_group_id, value) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?) 
on conflict (aggregate_type, consumer_group_id) " +
                    " do update SET VALUE = ? 
WHERE
  event_log_poller_state.aggregate_type = ? AND
  event_log_poller_state.consumer_group_id = ?
```

I get syntax error 42000

I're written following program to demonstrate

https://github.com/tonymurphy/h2-postgres

Edit Oct 2019: Checkout https://github.com/whisklabs/docker-it-scala or testcontainers.org

Comment: seems like it's just not possible.. shame postgres doesn't have an in memory version for test purposes

Comment: I now use docker and testcontainers.org or https://github.com/whisklabs/docker-it-scala

Comment: Recently there was a [merge](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/pull/2008) for supporting this in H2, but ON CONFLICT seems to still fail for me on version 1.4.200

Comment: That merge is actually just a small change to support ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING. Unfortunately if you try adding the constraint (e.g. on conflict(id)) or adding anything other than 'NOTHING' (e.g. update) it will fail.

Comment: Is this still not supported in 2022?

Comment: The [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73502879/13963086) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77079935/13963086) below give a good workaround, but unfortunately that won't work if you're trying to use PostgreSQL in production and H2 in tests using the same SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

There is merge which should do the same: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/h2_database/h2_database_merge.htm

```
MERGE INTO tableName [ ( columnName [,...] ) ] 
[ KEY ( columnName [,...] ) ] 
{ VALUES { ( { DEFAULT | expression } [,...] ) } [,...] | select }
```

See also https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/2007#issuecomment-1152312049

Comment: Can you provide a conversion of the SQL in the OP's question into `MERGE INTO` syntax?