# Spring: Native Query in batch using query annotation in a Repository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-repositories

I've got to do **upserts** of thousands of records at a time, broken into batches of let's say 25 actual upserts at a time. The upsert is based on a unique constraint being service+key, and if the insert fails, it updates the value.

Note that I'm interested in the UPSERT case, not just standard inserts, as I want to avoid the extra db READ operations as well as this data is mostly static.

I'm using Spring with Postgres 14, and was thinking I'd do something like the following to do the upsert in a Repository class, but wanted to ensure that the upserts are done in batches if possible.

I've set the following spring boot properties, but don't see any log messages suggesting batching is happening:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 25
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts = true
```

Can I do it using a method like so, or do I have to do it another way, [like so possibly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25419488/26510)?

```java
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(
  nativeQuery = true,
  value =
      "INSERT INTO my_table "
          + "  (service, key, value, version) "
          + "VALUES "
          + "  (:service, :key, :value, :version) "
          + "ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT allow_one_value_per_service_key DO "
          + "  UPDATE "
          + "    SET "
          + "      value = excluded.value, version=my_table.version + 1 "
          + "    WHERE  "
          + "      my_table.value <> excluded.value")
void upsertValue(
      @Param("service") String service,
      @Param("key") String key,
      @Param("value") String value,
      @Param("version") int version
      );
```

EDIT: My goal is to only ever do DB inserts or updates in batches (single transaction per batch), and do nothing if the value hasn't changed. So for a new "service" that hasn't had any values inserted yet, I will be inserting about 5000 values at once, which I want to ensure is done in groups, to avoid overloading Postgres and causing large transaction logs.

EDIT 2: Note that if your using @DataJpaTest to test your upsert, it will fail with H2 database, as it doesn't support `INSERT ON CONFLICT(unique) UPDATE. [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73502879/26510)

Comment: What is your goal? Throughput? Get rid of batches, load data into temporary table, avoiding conflicts, and them move to target table.

Comment: I will add some more info as an edit to the question... thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of other answers mentioned somethings related to `GenerationType.IDENTITY` or the hibernate batch properties such as `jdbc.batch_size` etc. , but these things are only matter if you batch update the records in the hibernate ways which is through its dirty checking mechanism or `EntityManager` 's `persist()` or `merge()`. If you are using the native SQL to update , it has nothing to do with these settings.

Fundamentally , batch executing native SQL requires to use JDBC 2.0 Batch API but there are no easy ways to access these API through hibernate API. So I would recommend to use `JdbcTemplate` which has a `batchUpdate()` method that will delegate to JDBC 2.0 Batch API `PreparedStatement#addBatch()` for the actual work.

Given you already had the native upsert SQL , it is actually very easy to do it via `JdbcTemplate`.

Firstly , define a record for `my_table` :

```
public record MyTable(String service, String key, String value, int version){}
```

Then implement a service for upserting them :

```
@Service
public class MyTableService {

    @Autowired
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jt;

    @Transactional
    public void upsert(List<MyTable> rows) {

        String sql = "INSERT INTO my_table "
                + "  (service, key, value, version) "
                + "VALUES "
                + "  (:service, :key, :value, :version) "
                + "ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT allow_one_value_per_service_key DO "
                + "  UPDATE "
                + "    SET "
                + "      value = excluded.value, version=my_table.version + 1 "
                + "    WHERE  "
                + "      my_table.value <> excluded.value";

        MapSqlParameterSource[] params = rows.stream().map(r -> {
            MapSqlParameterSource paramValues = new MapSqlParameterSource();
            paramValues.addValue("service", r.service());
            paramValues.addValue("key", r.key());
            paramValues.addValue("value", r.value());
            paramValues.addValue("version", r.version());
            return paramValues;
        }).toArray(MapSqlParameterSource[]::new);

        jt.batchUpdate(sql, params);

    }
}
```

To use it :

```java
List<MyTable> records = new ArrayList<>();
records.add(new MyTable("service1", "key1", "value1", 0));
records.add(new MyTable("service2", "key2", "value2", 0));
records.add(new MyTable("service3", "key3", "value3", 0));
records.add(new MyTable("service4", "key4", "value4", 0));
myTableService.upsert(records);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought why can't you use JpaRepository method saveAllAndFlush to insert into database

Just create an entity and Repository implementing JpaRepository

Also before inserting check for constraint

if exists :
value = {your value} and version++
else : save all of them to database

Comment: yeah originally that's what I had, is a read, check value, then a write if needed. So that's at least a read for every value, and then possibly a write. If I do it as above, then it's a single operation against the db, and it may result in no writes at all, especially for records which are unchanged (which is most of them, most of the time.) The original way, with the read, then write, will always require a read, which is more DB operations than I need 99% of the time. 99% of the time, the query I use in my answer won't do anything, which is a good thing!

Answer (score 1):

One thing that could explain why Hibernate is not performing your upserts as batches is that you are using `GenerationType.IDENTITY` for the definition of your entity.

This behavior has been reported here in SO previously, for example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63604753/jpa-batch-size-property-does-not-work-for-native-query).

Vlad Mihalcea explains the reasoning behind this behavior in [its excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697810/why-does-hibernate-disable-insert-batching-when-using-an-identity-identifier-gen).

Please, try getting rid of this generation process, maybe creating a compound primary key based on the fields `service` and `key` for your entity. Please, consider read [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032948/how-to-create-and-handle-composite-primary-key-in-jpa) for reference.